# How save LinearGradient To database

Tags: html, database, canvas, linear-gradients

I dynamically paint figures witch javascript in a HTML canvas and I need to use a linear gradient to fill style the figures  and save that information to a database

If I try to do a JSON.stringify on the linear gradient object only return "{}"

```
var grd = this.context.createLinearGradient(dx,(dy), (dx + 60 * 3),(dy + 50));
grd.addColorStop(0, "white");
grd.addColorStop(0.5, "red");
grd.addColorStop(1, "black");
```

I want to store that object to use in many figures dynamically with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can turn the linearGradient into an object, but what you could do is store the `dx` and `dy` as a JSON object and any other values you want to send to the database. Then store it in a database.

For example:

```
var grd = this.context.createLinearGradient(dx,(dy), (dx + 60 * 3),(dy + 50));
grd.addColorStop(0, "white");
grd.addColorStop(0.5, "red");
grd.addColorStop(1, "black");
var thingSentToDB = {dx: dx, dy:dy, colorOne: "white", colorTwo: "red", colorThree: "black"};
var jsonifiedThing = JSON.stringify(thingSentToDB);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have used this approach it works for what I want to do thank you so much